# Understanding DataSource, Session Factory, Transaction Manager and JPA Template

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using a configuration in my spring-hibernate application. The configuration is given below. **My Question is, what the purposes & duties of, `DataSource`, `sessionFactory`, `Transaction Manager` and `JPA Template` here. And why one bean id is used in another one.**

```
<!-- DataSource -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="net.softengine.edu.model"/>
</bean>

<!-- Transaction Manager-->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
<!-- JPA Template -- >
<bean id="jpaTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

Comment: You have to follow a Tutorial on Spring + Hibernate + JPA. You can not expect answers for question like this on Stackoverflow.

Comment: And SessionFactory is nothing at all to do with the JPA API